# How to evaluate a limit with subtractions $\lim_{x \rightarrow -1}(\frac{3}{x^3+1}-\frac{1}{x+1})$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm having trouble thinking of a way to solve this.
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow -1}\left(\frac{3}{x^3+1}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)$$

Comment: Should the first denominator have a plus sign instead of minus?

Comment: Use limit laws to split the limit into the difference of two different limits.

Comment: @DavidH Yes, it should, my mistake, I'll edit it.

Comment: @Tim Oh, thanks, I didn't knew there were some!(I missed some classes)

Comment: I see that the first minus sign was a mistake, so this no longer applies!

Now you should instead find a common denominator for the two fractions, and then factor to cancel out like terms. (An $(x+1)$ term will cancel to prevent the limit from blowing up)

Comment: @Tim Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because$$x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$we get
$$\frac{3}{x^3+1}-\frac{1}{x+1}=\frac{3}{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)}-\frac{1}{x+1}$$
$$=\frac{3-(x^2-x+1)}{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)}=\frac{x-x^2+2}{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)}=$$
$$=\frac{x+1-(x^2-1)}{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)}=\frac{(x+1)(2-x)}{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)}=\frac{2-x}{x^2-x+1}$$

Comment: Thanks, that solved it to me. :)

Comment: Yes, I solved it the same, thanks again! :)

Comment: You are welcome I am glad that helped you